# iOS App upgrading from existing app

Tags: ios

I have an app, it has two versions, a lite version(free) and a pro version(paid).

Now my need is to upgrade lite version to pro while go through a link from lite version.

After upgrading the lite version should not be in the device. Only pro version should appear in the device.

Is it possible to do this, if yes how can I implement this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling an app in code is not possible, but you should take a look at [In App Purchases](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to unlock Pro functionality in the free version.

Comment: is it posible to upgrade existing app by a link

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with link. You CAN trigger an In App Purchase transaction with a button, but you will have to implement the while unlocking features yourself. Other than that, you can link to the Pro version on the App Store, where the user can install the Pro version, but this will not remove the free version, nor will it transfer any data in the free to the Pro version.